# JMX enabling my Application using Jetty as embedded server

Tags: java, jetty, jmx, embedded-jetty

I have a java server application that would like to provide Http
interface to for administrative tasks such as monitoring and
configuring it at run-time and such.

I have some idea that JMX would provide me with a neat standard
interface that if I implement, I would provide a nice standard
management interface that ALL types of management console applications
can use to administor my Server application.

I am wondering if Jetty has a part to play in all of this running
in-process (embedded) into my java application?

what do you think is a best way of managing/monitoring my java application using a web interface?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We added a jmx rest interface option in jetty some time ago that might be useful here.

http://webtide.intalio.com/2011/05/jetty-jmx-webservice/

It could easily be pulled from for an admin like interface for management or presentation purposes.

Comment: @Thanks Jesse. Any idea how to add security for the in-house http port etc. For production/UAT i would like to add credentials to access this jmx page.

Comment: When setting up your handler chain, put the security handler in front of it and configure accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

JMX would allow you to expose configuration points for your application. This is required if you desire a programmatic/automated way of configuring your application. Using JMX to configure application is not desirable for a naive users. It is not very likely that they would know how to use JMX. Instead a graphical console would appeal to them. They can simply see what they need to configure, refer any reference material or help and just do it.

It is desirable that you have both the options; a web console and also the JMX way for programmatic access.

Secondly, you dont need a any third party server to JMX-enable your application. You simply create an instance of MBeanServer and it will host your mbeans.

Comment: Thanks @Vikas. Point is, JMX interface will be used by the support personnel or any admins, who should be authorized to do these tasks. So i would say it is ok for web interface. but ofcouse with security.